# Close button in leanModal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there I got small problem , i need add to my leanmodal close button pic
I already got close.png but I dont know how to add this to code. Any help ?

My function looks like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){
      $('#loginform').submit(function(e){       return false;     });        
      $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" }); }); 

</script>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Suggestions below doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the css of class "hidemodal" right in order to make it work.

On the example of [leanModal's website](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/#) (by analyzing the source code), you have this line of code :

```
.modal_close { position: absolute; 
               top: 12px; 
               right: 12px; 
               display: block; 
               width: 14px; 
               height: 14px; 
               background: url(../img/modal_close.png); 
               z-index: 2;}
```

So you need to change `.modal_close` by `.hidemodal` and to adjust this code to your desires.

Another problem is that you need to have a `<a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>` in your html code, it is not auto-added by leanModal plugin.

Comment: I specified the following but close button still dosen't show .modal_close { position: absolute; 
               top: 12px; 
               right: 12px; 
               display: block; 
               width: 14px; 
               height: 14px; 
               background: url(assets/images/modal_close.png); 
               z-index: 2;
}

Comment: @johnsam can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/452xdydf/1/ it won't run as it still requires jquery.leanModal.min.js. But it gives the idea.

Comment: here is your working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/452xdydf/10/
I will update my answer.

Comment: You're welcome and can upvote if it helped (I'd prefer you to accept the answer, would have been more useful, but given you are not the author it is impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Add it via a CSS declaration

```
  .hidemodal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(../img/close.png); <---- Add it here
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

Comment: I done something like this and still not working 
.modal_close { 
position: absolute; 
top: 12px; 
right: 12px; 
display: block; 
width: 14px; 
height: 14px; 
background: url("../images/close.png"); 
z-index: 11000;
}

i also change .modalHide for .modal_close

Comment: Perhaps your image is not in the right place on your server.  You could perhaps try it with a direct URL such as `background: url(http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/img/modal_close.png);`

Comment: Done and still nothing dont know why